# Prevent user from submitting a value that is out of range

Tags: c#

I have this block of code in my C# program (which is currently designed for adults between ages 25 - 30 year old)

```cs
Console.Write("Please enter in your age in the range of 25 - 30 years old: ");

string age = Console.ReadLine();
```

When user is prompted, I would like them to only enter values 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 or 30

I do not want user to be entering in a number outside the range.

Is there a way I can prevent this, so that when the user enter in a value outside of the range, a message will be displayed saying the user has entered in a inappropriate number?

Comment: Well you can use `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse` to get an integer value from your string value, and then check if it fits your needs. Depending on your platform, you might be able to use a validator to handle this

Comment: You can use a `while`-loop.

Answer (score 6):

Andrei's answer is good, however I would recommand using `int.TryParse` instead, as your users might enter *stupid* values that would otherwise crash your program (e.g: with non-digit characters):

```cs
Console.Write("Please enter in your age in the range of 25 - 30 years old: ");

int age;

while (true)
{
    string strAge = Console.ReadLine();
    // checks input validity (integer and within [25-30] range)
    if (int.TryParse(strAge, out age) && age >= 25 && age <= 30)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
        // ... and we leave the loop
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong input, please try again");
        // ... and we go back to ReadLine
    }
}
```

**Bonus:** Above code uses a loop so your users can keep entering values until they finally meet the criteria

Answer (score 2):

The most simpliest way is using an `if` statement. *But you need to convert your age first into an int using Convert.ToInt32 or int.Parse*

```
Console.Write("Please enter in your age in the range of 25 - 30 years old: ");
int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if(age <= 30 && age >= 25)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your age is not valid!");
}
```

Comment: why not use TryParse tho?

Comment: You're welcome @rpietkiewicz! You can upvote it and mark it as answer

Comment: @GogoDev, I use the simplest method because maybe he don't know how `TryParse` work yet

Comment: @AndreiSolero aight aight.

Comment: Using `int.Parse` is not good because the program will throw an exception if the user enters something that is not a number. Lack of knowledge of `TryParse` is irrelevant.